# PHP SESSION ID not getting passed into the browser

Tags: php, html, session, web

Let me explain the issue which might be strange, but i am undergoing through it from 3 days.

All of a sudden my session variables stopped working in my website.**Note:  no code changes**.

I raised a ticket and none of the technical specialists in my web hosting server gave me a correct answer.  In fact they said scripting issue, How can be it is a scripting issue which worked fine before.

After few hours, it worked **Note: This time also no code change**.  Our Engineers said it might be because of **some temporary issue** and will never occur in future

**Today Again my session variables stopped Working.**

Can Any one please try to understand what might be happening Since i am banging my head to know the root cause.

**Please guys help me out**

Note : No code changes at any point of time.  Same code worked absolutely fine before.  What might be the Issue at Server Level?

I checked by debugging in google chrome and noticed that session id is not getting passed into the browser.  Please help me out

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'stopped working'. Were the sessions being fetched from a database? Could the database have been down? It could be any number of things. Without more information I'm not sure that this question is answerable.

Comment: how long are you expecting the session variables to last? By default I think they only last for 24 minutes, so, after that you'd need to execute the script that sets them, i.e. if they are only being set on login for example. http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Comment: @shennan Sessions are not being fetched from database.  Declared session variable $_SESSION['NAME]=$username; in page 1 and trying to echo $_SESSION['NAME'] in second page as simple as that.  Thanks shennan

Comment: Its not even 5 minutes. I logged in and dashboard suppose to have username if session variables are worked.  Note: The same code worked absolutely fine without any issue.  Thanks martincarlin87

Comment: Could you check the session data, either using `phpinfo()` or echoing out the `ini_get` for the session related variables. I'm most interested in seeing `session.save_handler` (normally 'files'), `session.gc_maxlifetime` (How long do the vars hang around after their last usage before we delete them) and `session.cookie_domain` (if set wrong your cookies will be rejected and thus won't work).

Comment: Hi Scragar, Please find the below information as requested PHP Version 5.3.13
session.gc_maxlifetime=1440
session.save_handler = files
session.cookie_domain = no value

Comment: @scragar PHP Version 5.3.13
session.gc_maxlifetime=1440
session.save_handler = files
session.cookie_domain = no value

Comment: @user3762051 that looks fine then, unsure why you'd be having problems unless the location it stores the session files to is having difficulty storing the results. What's the `session.save_path`, if it's empty it will use the temp directory that can be obtained by executing `echo sys_get_temp_dir();`

Comment: @scragar : Thanks for the input. My session.save_path value : /home/users/web/b15863/ipg.myuserid/cgi-bin/tmp.  I am facing this issue from 2 days without any code changes, session variables stopped working and after it resumed working, now again it stopped.  Can not understand what's happening too..

Comment: Could you attempt to create a file there yourself using something like: `file_put_contents('/home/users/web/b15863/ipg.myuserid/cgi-bin/tmp/test_file_name', str_repeat('0123456789', 10));` If this throws an error you know for definite that the sessions aren't working because of a problem with the directory.

Comment: @scragar Is there any file limit at session.save_path directory? Because i can see files from June 21st till date.  In my logout.php i clearly defined unset($_SESSION['usernow']);
session_destroy(); also.  Anything else i need to do?

Comment: @user3762051 The file limit on linux is massive, it's highly unlikely you're going to have 100,000+ files in there, it's far more likely you'll experience an error on the drives, a permissions error or run out of space in general.

Comment: @scragar : I attempted to create file_put_contents('/home/users/web/b15863/ipg.myuserid/cgi-bin/tmp/test_file_na‌​me', str_repeat('0123456789', 10)); and can able to see the new file created in the above directory.

Comment: @scragar can you suggest any other debugging method's to dive into the issue please

Comment: @user3762051 OK, if you can write to the file and read it the next thing is to try and debug the headers sent by the browser, let's make sure that the browser is actually getting told the right session ID so it can pass it back later. Could you open your login page in chrome, open the dev console with F12, go to the networking tab, check "Perserve Log", then log in. You'll see the page that handles your logins appear, if you click it it'll open the details to the right. Look at the cookies subtab for a cookie called something like _PHPSESSIONID

Comment: @scragar I followed your steps but could not able to find anything under cookies tab like _PHPSESSIONID. I can see two things request cookies and response cookies.  Under request cookies i have only is_mobile parameter apart from that nothing

Comment: @user3762051 Do you have a page or two as a sample I can check this out with? Should at least be attempting to set cookies.

Comment: @scragar Sure Check out this code testing2.php

Comment: @scragar : testing2.php code
<?php 
    session_start();
    $username='sample';
    $_SESSION['usernow']=$username;
    echo $username;
    echo"<h4>Login Succesfull, <a href='testing3.php'>Click here</a> to enter your profile page</h4><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
?>

Comment: @scragar testing3.php <?php 
    session_start();
    
    $username=$_SESSION['usernow'];
    echo $username;
    echo"<h4>Hi $username<a href='logout.php'>Click here</a> to logout</h4><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
?>

Comment: @scragar Not getting any value after Hi, It suppose to me HI user name right?

Comment: @user3762051 The issue is most likely something on your server, I was asking for a link to the actual pages so I could check the headers myself for anything that looks suspicious.

Comment: @scragar Ok ok i am sorry i didn't get it. www.tringvoip.com/login.php username : sai*trinvoip, password : sai123.  Later it will redirect to another page Login successful, click here click on that then it will take you to www.tringvoip.com/login_ops.php where on the right side you will see welcome '', it suppose to be welcome username

Comment: @user3762051 OK, that page is not even attempting to set the cookie. Do you have access to any error logs? If errors are turned off and there is anything(even a new line or space) printed before the `session_start()` call it would explain the behaviour.

Comment: @scragar, Error logs are off.  So before session_start() in www.tringvoip.com/login_ops.php i echoed"Thanks a lot scragar for your kind assistance" and i could see it in browser too.  Please check once.  Thanks

Comment: @user3762051 That echo is appearing in the body, way after other content is being written to the page. Is there something you're including before that point that could be writing content out?

Comment: @scragar can u check it now first thing which i am doing is echoing the string. Later i am coding my html doc.

Comment: @scragar See now the session variables are working you can see welcome username over there and u know we did nothing right or is it because you are setting something?

Comment: @scragar Now not working again

Comment: @scragar Sorry for disturbing you too many times.  Any other way to troubleshoot this please let me know

Comment: @user3762051 I don't understand, your page isn't working because your content is being written and the headers closed before the session starts(which means it can't send the cookie to keep you logged in). There's a `headers_sent()` function that will confirm this is the issue.

Comment: @scragar ok you tell me your findings about the session so that i will ask the same question to my web hosting service provider which may be useful for them to get back to me with the root cause.  Thanks

Comment: @user3762051 It's not your provider at fault, your testing pages work fine because the `session_start();` is the very first thing you do, there must be something on your other pages that is causing that to fail. Is the session_start() the first thing on the page? Very first, before anything else?

Comment: @scragar Yes session_start() is at the beginning.  Even testing pages didn't work for me i mean testing2.php and testing3.php what i gave you before also didn't work

Comment: @scragar It's working now I don't know how. But its such a great interaction with you and heavily thankful to your inputs and time.  Thanks a lot.  If the issue occur's again i will share all the inputs provided by you to our hosting server team and I am waiting for them to get back to me on this too.  Thanks again a lot. Even testing files which i gave before is also working fine.  Any time if you identify something what might be the issue and share to me in the its a very great help for me.  But really thank u again